# What are some good cheap self-watering containers?

Tags: containers

I've made my own self-watering containers. Fun, but a bit time-consuming.

Most self-watering containers that are for sale are a bit pricey for me... I'd really want at least a half a dozen, and at $30 or so each, this is a strain.

So... anything that you can buy in the $12 and under range that will serve the purpose? I think ideally it would NOT be marketed as a SWC, but rather something that can be easily adapted for the purpose.

Again, just to be clear ... not looking for the DIY solutions.

Comment: You are "not looking for the DIY solutions", but you also don't want something marketed as SWC but which can be "easily adapted for the purpose". These seem to be contradictory requirements.

Comment: @Portabella - what size container are you looking for?

Comment: Also what is your general location? US? Europe? Somewhere else?

Comment: @jsbangs - They can be marketed as SWC or not, as long as they are cheap. I suspect that anything marketed as SWC will NOT be cheap, but I'm willing to be proven wrong.

Comment: @waxeagle I'm in the US. Size: the bigger is better.

Comment: @Portabella - do you care if they are plastic?

Comment: Is your garden outside? Are you out for travel?

Answer (score 7):

If you do not mind plastic self watering containers I have two suggestions.

I have used [these](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Mainstays-5.2-Self-Watering-Planter/16630836) and [this](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Mainstays-18-Self-Watering-Window-Box/16630838) with a great deal of success. The first one comes in a variety of sizes and they are relatively inexpensive, especially the smaller ones. However, because I don't remember how much they are and because Walmart isn't everywhere yet (they are only sold in store not online). I have also located [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GXW3V4) on Amazon. They look to be pretty much the same design.

I have used the ones sold at Walmart for herbs and I currently have tomato and pepper seedlings growing in the window box one. They are pretty good although the round pots I have are a bit small for my purposes. However, that is just because I am a cheapskate and haven't bought the proper sized pots.